# Maclaurin series of the function $\frac{x^2}{2+3x^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I got this question:

Find the Maclaurin series of the function $\frac{x^2}{2+3x^2}$ and find its domain of convergence.

I tried using the binomial series $(1+x)^m = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{m \choose k}x^k$ where $-1<x<1$ and substituting $-1$ for $m$  and $1+3x^2$ for $x$ and then I'll get  that $\frac{x^2}{2+3x^2} = x^2(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k(1+3x^2)^k)$, but since the formula is true only for $-1<x<1$ And thus I can use this formula only for $x$'s that satisfy $-1<1+3x^2<1$ which is equivalent to $\frac{-2}{3}<x^2<0$, but no $x$ satifies this condition, The same thing I get if I use the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$ since this formula is true only for $x$'s that satisfy $-1<x<1$.
After that I tried to find it using the definition of Maclauring series by finding the nth derivative at $x = 0$ but the $n$-th derivative formula seems to be very complex.
The first six term according to Wolfram|Alpha are:
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3x^4}{4}+\frac{9x^6}{8}-\frac{27x^8}{16}+\frac{81x^{10}}{32}-\frac{243x^{12}}{64}+\cdots$$
But I don't know how to get that series.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{x^{2}}{2+3x^{2}} = \frac{x^{2}}{2} \frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{2}x^{2}}$.

For all $u \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vert u \vert < 1$, we have :

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}u^{n} = \frac{1}{1+u} $$

Substituting $u$ with $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}x^{2}$ leads to :

$$ \frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{2}x^{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n} \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^{n} x^{2n} $$

As a consequence,

$$ \frac{x^{2}}{2+3x^{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}} 3^{n} x^{2n+2} $$

which is valid as long as $\displaystyle \Big\vert \frac{3}{2}x^{2} \Big\vert < 1$, which is equivalent to $x \in \left] -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \right[$.

Comment: Nice answer. Why are your brackets reversed on the last line?

Comment: @alexqwx : because the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n} \Big( \frac{3}{2} \Big)^{n} x^{2n}$ does not converge at $\displaystyle x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: No, I mean why is it not $$\left[ -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \right]$$?

Comment: @alexqwx : because the series given at the end does not converge at $\displaystyle x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. Substitute $x$ with one of these two points in the last expression.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{2}x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3^n}{2^n}x^{2n},$$ we deduce that
$$
\frac{x^2}{2+3x^2} = \frac{x^2}{2} \frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{2}x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3^n}{2^{n+1}}x^{2n+2}
$$
This expansion holds true provided that the first expansion holds true, namely $\frac{3}{2}x^2<1$.